# Creating a Cmd on a form to go directly to a specific record

Tags: vba, ms-access

When creating a Cmd on a form to go directly to a specific record it goes there but then when clicking on the Cmd Next it does not work?

I first created a Sub to use in my Next and Previous Record Command Buttons:

```
'''
Sub MvToRec(frm As Form, mv As Access.AcRecord)

On Error Resume Next
    DoCmd.GoToRecord , frm.Name, mv
    Select Case Err.Number
    Case 0 'no error
    Case 2105
        'if first record reached jump to last and vice versa
        Select Case mv
        Case acNext: mv = acFirst
        Case acPrevious: mv = acLast
        End Select
        MvToRec frm, mv
    Case Else
        Debug.Print Err.Number, Err.Description
    End Select   
End Sub
'''
```

And then I use this sub for my Next (cmdNextRecord) or Previous (cmdPreviousRecord) Command Buttons:

```
'''
Private Sub cmdNextRecord_Click()
    MvToRec Me, acNext
End Sub

Private Sub cmdPreviousRecord_Click()
    MvToRec Me, acPrevious
End Sub
'''
```

Then I created a Command Button 'CmdGoTo' that reads a certain record number inserted by the user (Me.TxtID) and opens that particular record:

```
'''
Private Sub CmdGoTo_Click() 
Dim strsearch As String
Dim Task As String

'Check if a Paper ID entered or not
If IsNull(Me.TxtID) Or Me.TxtID = "" Then
   MsgBox "Please type in your paper ID.", vbOKOnly, "Paper ID Needed"
   Me.TxtID.BackColor = vbYellow
   Me.TxtID.SetFocus
Else
    strsearch = Me.TxtID.Value
    Task = "SELECT * FROM Papers WHERE ((ID Like ""*" & strsearch & "*""))"
    Me.RecordSource = Task
    Me.TxtID.BackColor = vbWhite
End If
End Sub
'''
```

So once I open the form my next and previous command buttons work like a charm but when I use my GoTo command button... for example if the user type in 22 and than Click GoTo it goes to the record 22 which is good but then if the user now tries to use the next or previous buttons it goes to record 122 or to 222 or then to 322 but it never goes to 23 (for Next) or 21 (for Previous)? I don't understand why? Can someone help me with this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You changed the `RecordSource` to all and only those records that match your pattern `LIKE *22*` (in your example with "22" entered). So if you have records with ID values from 1 to 1000 then after executing your `CmdGoTo_Click` only records 22, 122, 220, 221, 222, ..., 229, 322, 422, ... and so on remain in your form's record source. Therefore the next after 22 is 122.

You may use `DoCmd.FindRecord` (-> [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/access.docmd.findrecord)) or `Recordset.FindFirst` (-> [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/recordset-findfirst-method-dao)) instead of changing the forms record source.